# Reset form and validation on submit using javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to reset all form field when click submit.

I have tried document.getElementById("register").reset() and it work but validation lines does not removing and keep required expression exsist

```
  function reset() {
  document.getElementById("register").reset();
}
```

[This what happen when click submit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kg7nV.png)

Comment: Hi, it's a bit impossible to understand what's the problem without the actual code. Those messages aren't native and aren't generated from browsers, so you are showing/hiding them on some condition

Comment: Are you using bootstrap 4? If so, you need to remove the `.was-validated` class from the form. As Cristian says, we need more context to provide more accurate help.

Comment: I make validation using javaScript function

Comment: It looks as if somehow your form is being either reset and then submitted or submitted twice in quick succession. Without proper information it's a guessing game. Please read how to post a [mcve]